Extracting ground points from LiDAR LAZ data using python and qgis
I have a LAZ dataset which has 30 million points. I want to do following setps in python and QGIS (if there is a way) inorder to achieve my goal.
01.convert my LAZ data format to LAS format
02.filter the ground point clasification (clasification =2) at the same time filter only  'last return' type
03  save the data as .las file format

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
